# Routing Angular JS Not Working and not throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I tried to use `$routeProvider`. But something wrong and i dont know what. Console not throwing error and nothing happen in my page. Im confused. Any solution for me ?

This my code :

```
var app = angular.module("admin-rv-app", ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            // route for the thread page
            .when('/thread', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/thread.html',
                controller  : 'threadController'
            });

    });

app.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome Home";
});

app.controller('threadController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Thread";
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="title">Home</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#thread">
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="title">Thread + Answer</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

By the way I have include `angular.min.js` and `angular.route.min.js` and `ng-app="admin-rv-app"`

Comment: include the `$scope` in the module.

Comment: Can you please put `<a href="/#/">` and `<a href="/#/thread">` and then try.

Comment: Its not working and redirect to page thread. Page thread is http://192.168.0.253:81/#/thread

Comment: I can't see ng-view added in your HTML have you added ng-view div to load the template dynamically?

Comment: Yes, ng-view to load template dynamically

Comment: Pasted the working code below.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you create your app.config.

```
    app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){  
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the thread page
        .when('/thread', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/thread.html',
            controller  : 'threadController'
        });   
}])
```

Try this out instead, and dont add $scope to the module, that will only give you more errors to handle.

Also change the  tag, to "/thread" instead of #.

You need to use $routeProvider for the .when statement, otherwise angular cant user the $routeProvider for your diffrent views

Comment: Still not working in my code. I change "/thread" in html but even redirect to page undefined

Comment: try switching to ng-href="/thread" instead of the normal href

Comment: Last thing i can think of, have you set the base tag <base href="/"> in your index?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still not working and showing many error

Answer (score 1):

Inject $location service in your controller

after that

```
<a ng-click="changeLocation()"/>
```

and

```
$scope.changeLocation = function (){
    $location.path('/thread')
}
```

Comment: if I use $location.path. Can $location.path make redirect like $routeProvider ?

Comment: $location service is used along with $routeProvider or if you want to go with the current code then see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cmckeachie/mtV62/
means use `<a href="#/thread">`

Answer (score 1):

try using this in HTML:

```
<li>
        <a href="#home">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="title">Home</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#thread">
            <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="title">Thread + Answer</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

And change the router code to this:

```
 app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/home', {
              templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/home.html',
              controller: 'homeController'
           })

            // route for the thread page
            .when('/thread', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/thread.html',
                controller  : 'threadController'
            });

    });
```

If you notice I have changed the URL from "/" to "/home" 
and I checked, it is working. Let me if it's not working at your end

Comment: This code is working at my end. Could you paste the complete HTML code as well ?